# Printing_Alice's library after rearrangement

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, stack

I'm trying to solve the following problem  using stack but I think my logic is wrong  (*I'm getting error* )can anyone help me with this,(I'm new to DSA)

Alice is rearranging her library. She takes the innermost shelf and reverses the order of books. She breaks the walls of the shelf. In the end, there will be only books and no shelf walls. Print the order of books.

Opening and closing walls of shelves are shown by '/' and '' respectively whereas books are represented by lower case alphabets.

**Sample Input**
/u/love\i\
**Sample Output**
iloveu

```py
  class Stack:

    def __init__(self):

        self.s=[]

        self.f=[]

    def lib(self,x):

        for i in range(len(x)+1):
            
            if x[i].isalpha():
                self.s.append(x[i])
            elif x[i]=='/':
                self.s.append(x[i])
            elif x[i]=='\\':
                while self.s[i]!='/' and len(self.s)>0:
                    self.f.append(self.s.pop())

                return self.f             

if __name__=='__main__':

    x="/u/love\\i\\"

    x=list(x)

    print(x[:])

    d=Stack()

    print(d.lib(x))
```

Comment: What error are you getting specifically?

Comment: index out of range